# What char (or string) is invisible on screen but won't trigger required field failed?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a asp.net MVC application. On one page, there is a form which has a field. The mode the Required. It is possible for the user to input a char or string invisible on screen but does not fail the required field validation. The validation is the default asp.net MVC required validation. Or, initialize the model with a default value which is invisible on screen. So the user can't see it?

Now, we initialize it as 'N/A'. It works, but boss thinks it does not look nice.

Thanks

Comment: If it can have a default value...is it really a required field?

Answer (score 0):

`ModelState["{key}"].Errors.Clear();` This can remove the validtion errors on server side. On client side the error wont be shown unless you have validation summary. If you are displaying each error separately this would help or you can disable the validations by

```
@{ Html.EnableClientValidation(false); }
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SomeString)
@{ Html.EnableClientValidation(true); }
```

or

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SomeString, new { @data_val = "false" })
```